# Move constructor error

Tags: c++, math, sse, simd, move-constructor

I want to create a `vec3` class that uses a regular `vec3` class (non-`SIMD`) class if the data type is not of type `float` and use the `vec3` (`SIMD`) optimized class for data type `float`. I am stuck on how to properly use template specialization.

The problem is in the move constructors but I am starting to wonder if maybe the move constructors are not possible with template specialization.

NOTE: I am using `CLion`

Error

```
C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\171.4694.31\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe --build C:\Users\Matt\CLionProjects\RainyDayEngine\cmake-build-debug --target RainyDayEngine -- -j 8
Scanning dependencies of target RainyDayEngine
[ 10%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/RainyDayEngine.dir/main.cpp.obj
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/RainyDayEngine.dir/Engine/Core/Math/vec3.cpp.obj
In file included from C:\Users\Matt\CLionProjects\RainyDayEngine\Engine\Core\Math\vec3.cpp:5:0:
C:\Users\Matt\CLionProjects\RainyDayEngine\Engine\Core\Math\vec3.h:63:31: error: declaration of 'vec3<T>::vec3(vec3<T>&&)' has a different exception specifier
 vec3<T>::vec3 (vec3<T> &&other)
                               ^
C:\Users\Matt\CLionProjects\RainyDayEngine\Engine\Core\Math\vec3.h:34:2: error: from previous declaration 'vec3<T>::vec3(vec3<T>&&) noexcept'
  vec3(vec3<T>&& other) noexcept;
  ^
CMakeFiles\RainyDayEngine.dir\build.make:262: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/RainyDayEngine.dir/Engine/Core/Math/vec3.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/RainyDayEngine.dir/Engine/Core/Math/vec3.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from C:\Users\Matt\CLionProjects\RainyDayEngine\main.cpp:6:0:
C:\Users\Matt\CLionProjects\RainyDayEngine\Engine/Core/Math/vec3.h:63:31: error: declaration of 'vec3<T>::vec3(vec3<T>&&)' has a different exception specifier
 vec3<T>::vec3 (vec3<T> &&other)
                               ^
C:\Users\Matt\CLionProjects\RainyDayEngine\Engine/Core/Math/vec3.h:34:2: error: from previous declaration 'vec3<T>::vec3(vec3<T>&&) noexcept'
  vec3(vec3<T>&& other) noexcept;
  ^
CMakeFiles\RainyDayEngine.dir\build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/RainyDayEngine.dir/main.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/RainyDayEngine.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/RainyDayEngine.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/RainyDayEngine.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [RainyDayEngine] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/RainyDayEngine.dir/all' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/RainyDayEngine.dir/rule' failed
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'RainyDayEngine' failed
```

vec3.h

```
template <typename T>
class vec3
{
public:
    vec3();
    vec3(T *pval);
    vec3(T x, T y, T z);
    vec3(const vec3<T>& other);
    vec3(vec3<T>&& other) noexcept;
    void print() { std::cout << "hello regular" << std::endl; }
protected:
    struct {
        T x, y, z;
    };
};

template <typename T>
vec3<T>::vec3 ()
        : x(0), y(0), z(0)
{}

template <typename T>
vec3<T>::vec3 (T *pval)
        : x(pval[0]), y(pval[1]), z(pval[2])
{}

template <typename T>
vec3<T>::vec3 (T x, T y, T z)
        : x(x), y(y), z(z)
{}

template <typename T>
vec3<T>::vec3 (const vec3<T> &other)
        : x(other.x), y(other.y), z(other.z)
{}

template <typename T>
vec3<T>::vec3 (vec3<T> &&other)
        : x(std::move(other.x)), y(std::move(other.y)), z(std::move(other.z))
{}
```

vec3_sse.h

```
template <>
class vec3<float>
{
public:
    vec3()
        : m_data(_mm_setzero_ps())
    {}
    vec3(float *pval)
        : m_data(_mm_load_ps(pval))
    {}
    vec3(float x, float y, float z)
        : m_data(_mm_setr_ps(x, y, z, z))
    {}
    vec3(const vec3& other)
        : m_data(other.m_data)
    {}
    vec3(vec3&& other) noexcept
        : m_data(std::move(other.m_data))
    {}
    operator __m128() const { return m_data; }
    void print() { std::cout << "hello simd" << std::endl; }
protected:
    __m128 m_data;
};
```

Comment: You're missing the `noexcept` specifier

Comment: Do you realize that move constructors in your case are useless unless your vectors' contents allocate memory dynamically? Also, FYI, your copy/move constructors work same as default ones, thus you don't even need to declare them explicitely.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It might be useful if he uses a vec3 of arbitrary precision numbers (like mpfr).

Comment: @chtz Even then it is still not needed.  As long as the template type is copyable/moveable the defaults will be appropriate.  Unless `vec3` is doing some dynamic memory allocation there is no reason to not use the defaults.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, you are right. Of course the default is sufficient here.

Comment: `vec3` is fundamentally a bad use of SIMD btw.

Comment: @harlod would like to explain further? also please keep in mind that this class is purely a test for the two classes and is no where near what I want it to be nor should be...

Comment: @O'Neil your comment solved the issue. If you would like to put it as the answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: I didn't get pinged by that.. anyway an immediate issue is that it's only using 3/4ths of the lanes, so that's immediately losing a quarter of the potential. It also takes up more space than necessary, reducing the effectiveness of the cache whenever working with multiple `vec3`s, and operations such as dot product/length/normalize would have inefficient implementations. So, generally, you should prefer SoA over AoS. For example computing 4 dot products in parallel is not wasteful.

Comment: @harlod I am very new to SIMD classes so if you do not mind expanding further on your point or pointing me to some articles about your grievances with the code so far.

Comment: Sure here's one: https://deplinenoise.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/gdc2015_afredriksson_simd.pdf (btw could you not write my name like that, I have to manually check back here to see responses if you do that)

Comment: For sure. How am I suppose to be writing names in comments?

Comment: With the same spelling as they actually are, if you type the first letters you should get an auto-complete popup thing above the textbox that you can click to automatically get the right spelling

Comment: @harold  Do you by chance of a working implementation of a vector3/vector4 class that properly utilizes SSE? I am not to sure how to implement one after reading the article you provide (great read)

Comment: There isn't one, that's the point, that abstraction doesn't work. The real "unit" is a collection of `vec3`, stored such that there is an array of `x`, an array of `y` and an array of `z`. (some other layouts also work, for example xxxxyyyyzzzz repeating, which may be better but it's even more annoying in C++)

Comment: @harlod  so if I understand you correctly is that you make a regular `vec3` class then when you need to do computation on a list of `vec3` classes you use SoA so that you can use `SSE` properly?

Comment: A `vec3` class isn't super useful when you do that, there is no "xyz" in memory so at best it would be a collection of static functions that manipulate the data in SoA layout - that might actually be a reasonable place to put these functions idk, that's more of a software engineering deal.. anyway I can write you some interesting functions if you want

Comment: @harlod  that would be really cool if you could do that. Would love to learn more about SoA.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149625/discussion-between-matthew-and-harold).